# How to use "Monotype Corsiva" font in CSS statement?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm not sure about what font it is but I assumed it as a Monotype Corsiva (please correct me if I'm wrong), and here's my current CSS which doesnt seem to work because the font didn't change a bit

CSS:

```
<div style="font-family:Monotype Corsiva, Times, Serif; background-color:#74b3bc; height:46px; minSize=10;maxSize=100;">
```

[image]

Comment: have you actually downloaded the font, converted it to a font kit and added it in your css? if not, google search "google font monotype corsiva" - by default browsers only natively supports a small list of fonts. the rest you have to load in yourself

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotype_Corsiva

Comment: Also, that font is copyright and is not free to use. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518783/how-to-add-custom-font-in-my-theme

Comment: It works just fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look on google fonts I'm sure you will find something similar. Here is an example of using Google web fonts with a font called "Cookie" and it is quite similar.

Firstly put this in your page ...

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Cookie:regular"]
      }
    });
</script>
```

and then to use it in your actual web page include it in your css like so.

```
body {
   font-family: "Cookie"
}
```

If you do check out google fonts you can add as many as you want using the javascript code above, just simply stick a comma between each font and make sure they are in quotes like this...

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
      WebFont.load({
      google: {
      families: ["Lato:100,300,400,700,900","Karla:regular","Cookie:regular"]
    }
    });
</script>
```

and the 100,300,400,700,900 - is the font weight, so by declaring it here you can use it in your css.

and to be safe here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKt8x/3/)

enjoy :)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is correct. There are syntax errors later in the style sheet, but they do not prevent the declaration `font-family:Monotype Corsiva, Times, Serif` from taking effect. It causes Monotype Corsiva to be used, if the user’s computer has such a font installed. Apparently, the computer where you tested this does not have that font.

Answer (score 1):

Add this script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
      WebFont.load({
      google: {
      families: ["Lato:100,300,400,700,900","Karla:regular","Cookie:regular"]
    }
    });
</script>
```

then add this style

```
<h2 style="font-family: Cookie;">Example</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the font is downloaded and installed on your server.
- And in CSS, your can write this simple code. It will work. It does for me.

```css
font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva';
```